# Probability of n people having at least k successes

Tags: poisson-distribution, discrete-data, rare-events

I have a set of numbers that corresponds to the number of objects per person,

$X = (1, 1, 2, 5, 10, 1, ...)$

The data's discrete, where it's highly inflated by 1 (no zeros) and you have a very long tail - almost like a Poisson. For my case in particular, I have about ~20 million objects distributed unevenly across ~1 million people.

I'm wondering what's the most appropriate distribution to use to describe the *number of people that would have at least 2 objects*, e.g. probability that 50 people have at least 2 objects or more.

I was thinking of using the Poisson in the form of

$P(X \geq 2) = 1 - (P(X = 0) + P(X = 1))$

but something tells me this models the *probability that **one** person has at least 2 objects* (which is almost certainly true)?

Please let me know of a good alternative! I was also thinking about a hypergeometric distribution, but that seemed odd because $K$ and $N$ would be identical...

Comment: Maybe I'm underthinking this a little bit, but your Poisson distribution can yield a split for any arbitrary cutoff (like 2). So using your formula you might say 20% have 0 or 1 objects, and 80% have 2 or more. And... that's it. If you're data set is 50 people, your expected value is 40 people. At this point it's just a proportions problem, and you can use the formula (p)(1-p) to calculate your variance for the proportion and slap a confidence interval on it.

Comment: I wouldn't say underthinking! It's just one step of the way there. The dataset (edited now) is about a million individuals, and I'm not even sure how I'd calculate the expected value here since the data's distributed unevenly (I can maybe assume a uniform of distribution of objects as a prior). Not sure I get you about "it's just a proportions problem" though. Also, since my population is really large, p -> 0 and so (p)(1-p) is going to be a very small value

Comment: P should be invariant to sample size. P is the proportion that meet your criteria. So in our 20%/80% split example the variance is always going to be 0.2*0.8. The nice thing about statistical theory is that the expected value of the population given your data is the expect value of your data, i.e. the mean of your data.

Comment: As far as being confident it fits a Poisson distribution, that's tricky, as distribution fit is tricky. However, if all you really care about is under/over a threshold, then we can just ignore it all together. Transform the data to binary 0/1 for over/under and then just work with the proportions. Am I understanding your question?